# Defect prevention audit

Tags: test-management, defect-tracking, test-strategy

This is  testing certification question .I think the ans will be B . Need your opinion

> During an Audit , Auditor asked for evidences that the defect
>   prevention activities are effective.Which of the below items which you will choose
>   as evidence

```
a. defect trend chart for the last quarter 
b. list of defects from last month and current month 
c. defect density report for last months 
d. control chart of defect trends with 8 months data
```

Comment: It is hard for me to follow this certification question. Can you provide correct English form?

Comment: @dzieciou I am preparing for testing certification .

Comment: I think dzieciou's point is that the grammar of what you quoted is very poor and difficult to understand, so if possible could you copy-paste the exact wording from wherever you got it from rather than writing it from memory.

Comment: @c32hedge I have rechecked this is the exact question .

Comment: What is the answer for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe defect density report is the artifact for this .